# How to get data using Selenium wihout opening Chrome browser?

Tags: python, arrays, string, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape *`Amazon product prices`*. And I want to scrape prices text without opening the Chrome browser. I searched this on the Internet but it didn't help me.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Driver and link
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/musta/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/b07h9fldcd")

getText = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-section a-spacing-micro").get_attribute("textContent")
print(getText)

driver.close()
```

But this didn't work. It keeps giving me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\musta\Desktop\asd.py", line 8, in <module>
    getText = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-section a-spacing-micro").get_attribute("textContent")
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a-section a-spacing-micro"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

What should I do? I'm stuck at here. I want to scrape price from given `div` without opening Chrome browser. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean to run the scripts in headless mode? Also what price are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need headless broswer I think :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/musta/Desktop/chromedriver.exe', options = options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/b07h9fldcd")
```

and regarding your error, in Selenium class name do not work with spaces :

so instead of this,

```
.a-section a-spacing-micro
```

do this with css :

```
.a-section.a-spacing-micro
```

so code should look like this :

```
getText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".a-section.a-spacing-micro").get_attribute("innerHTML")
print(getText.strip())
```

if it just the price you wanna grab, try with this css  :

```
span#price_inside_buybox
```

in code it would look like this  :

```
getText = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#price_inside_buybox
").text
print(getText.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your query:

1. You can open the chrome browser in headless mode so it wont render in frontend
2. Try to inspect element and confirm the id/class name you have used to get_attribute